# Loop through databases on server, and update data

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, loops

I have a server with multiple databases. I need to loop through these databases and change a value in one record, in one table, in each database. How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @query varchar(max)
set @query = ''

select  @query = @query + 'UPDATE ' + name + 
            '.dbo.YourTable set value = 1 where id = 2; '
from    master.sys.databases
where   name <> 'master'

exec (@query)
```

Comment: Thanks Andomar. I think this is more suited to my situation than the 'sp_MSForEachDB' stored procedure as I may need to be more custom with each database. Using this method I could create a loop, and various IF conditions to get the results I require. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB ' Use ?; UPDATE ?.dbo.MyTable SET MyValue=999  '
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an undocumented stored procedure sp_MSForEachDB which will execute SQL for each database.

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'PRINT ''?'''
```

The ? is the database name.