# loop and execute code on each database

Tags: t-sql

I am having trouble understanding why my query is not doing what it is supposed to do.  It's supposed to run the command in each database to get permissions, yet it seems to give the same permissions for each database as if it's running in the same one each time and just replacing the name of the database.  Thanks for any help.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @dbs TABLE (dbname VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @CurrentDB VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Permissions TABLE (DBName sysname, UserName sysname, 
LoginType sysname, AssociatedRole varchar(max),create_date datetime,
modify_date datetime)

INSERT INTO @dbs (dbname)
SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE state_desc != 'OFFLINE'
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT dbname FROM @dbs)
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentDB = (SELECT TOP 1 dbname FROM @dbs ORDER BY dbname)

        INSERT INTO @Permissions
        SELECT @CurrentDB AS DBName,
            case prin.name when 'dbo' then prin.name + ' ('+ (select SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) from master.sys.databases where name = @CurrentDB) + ')' else prin.name end AS UserName,
            prin.type_desc AS LoginType,
            isnull(USER_NAME(mem.role_principal_id),'') AS AssociatedRole ,create_date,modify_date

        FROM sys.database_principals prin
            LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_role_members mem ON prin.principal_id=mem.member_principal_id
        WHERE prin.sid IS NOT NULL and prin.sid NOT IN (0x00) and
        prin.is_fixed_role <> 1 AND prin.name NOT LIKE '##%'

DELETE FROM @dbs WHERE dbname = @CurrentDB

END

SELECT * FROM @Permissions
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206304/loop-through-databases-on-server-and-update-data) which relates to executing a statement in every database.